# THROW with percentage sign (%) produces strange error message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, throw

Executing the following T-SQL statement in SSMS<sup>1</sup> gives an error message that contains exactly one space<sup>2</sup>:

```
THROW 50000, 'abc%de', 0;

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
```

However, if I escape % by doubling it, I get the expected error message:

```
THROW 50000, 'abc%%de', 0;

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
abc%de
```

I also noticed that when % is followed by space, it is just skipped:

```
THROW 50000, 'abc% de', 0;

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
abc de
```

For some reason, THROW is interpreting % in a special way.

1. Does anybody know why?
2. Are there any other "special" characters?
3. Is this documented anywhere?

I have observed this behavior under MS SQL Server 2012 and 2014. I haven't tried other versions.

---

*<sup>1</sup> I have also tried ADO.NET, with equivalent results.*

*<sup>2</sup> This is not clearly visible here, but I have double-checked: the error message is indeed not an empty string, but exactly one space.*

Comment: Sounds like printf formatting options, %s, %d etc. Doesn't seem like it's possible to use them properly anyhow :(

Comment: You can use them by using the `FORMATMESSAGE` function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx. I assume this is the reason why the % is showing this behavior.

Comment: This answer might be of interest: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74249/24734 My guess is that it is either connected to the formatmessage function, or something left over from raiserror when throw were introduced. It doesn't look like intentional behaviour.

Comment: @JodyT: Except that doesn't really make sense, does it? It would be the FORMATMESSAGE function (which isn't being called in this context) doing the (possibly wrong) substitution, then.

Comment: Some other fun ones to try are `%r` and `%n`. I have a blog post half-written about this; thanks for the motivation to finish. I'll post a link when I'm done.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/fun-with-throw/ - still waiting on some sort of insight from my contacts at Microsoft on exactly what THROW is doing behind the scenes where it cares about %.

Comment: I heard back from Microsoft, and updated my blog post. Essentially, this is caused by a partial shared code path with RAISERROR, and you should get used to the behavior. They're not going to fix it, but they have agreed to add a note to the THROW documentation to indicate there are issues with the % character.

Answer (score 1):

**The documentation for THROW states:**

> The message parameter does not accept printf style formatting

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx

That should explain why it fails to print the text.

There is more information about printf style formating in SQL Server in the RAISERROR documentation (msg_str):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

**This will test characters from 0-255 to check if they will return something:**

```
DECLARE @errors TABLE(CharNumber INT, CharValue CHAR(1), ErrorText NVARCHAR(4000));
DECLARE @i INT = 0;

WHILE (@i <= 255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c CHAR(1) = CHAR(@i);

    DECLARE @m VARCHAR(50) = 'abc%' + @c + 'de';
    BEGIN TRY
        THROW 50000, @m, 0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO @errors
        SELECT @i, @c, ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM @errors WHERE ErrorText > '' ORDER BY CharNumber
```

**Output:**

```
CharNumber  CharValue   ErrorText
32      abc de
33  !   abc!de
37  %   abc%de
46  .   abc.de
48  0   abcde
110 n   abc
nde --<- This adds a new line.
```

%n = new line, but it do not remove n, that is a bit funny.

Comment: Yup I know it "does not accept printf style formatting", so why does it "accept" it, after a fashion?

Comment: Well, it must be a conscious design choice made by Microsoft. Since they state it so clearly in the documentation that "prinf formatting" is not accepted. It might be because they want us to use it differently, or maybe it is an internal technical challenge in SQL Server. But, since they do not accept it, they must blank out the message (or throw another error, which probably would be confusing). If they had written "do not support" i would had expected it to print your message. The reason that %% works is because you tell the function not use "printf formatting", which should be accepted.

Comment: Then why does `abc% de` produce `abc de`?

Comment: On a more general note: "not accept" can mean either "ignore" or "error". Obviously, THROW doesn't ignore it, and reporting an error by sometimes returning one-space string and sometimes returning some other string is a very strange "design choice" indeed, as opposed to using NULL or empty string or even something like `invalid message specified`. All in all, this looks like a bug.

Comment: Hehe, you do have some good points. We might have to interpret "do not accept" as "it might fail in some way if you use it" :) I have tested all characters from 0-255 and found that there are six characters that will not return blank: 32(space), 33(!), 37(%), 46(.), 48(0), 110(n) I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort (+1). Still doesn't answer my questions, unfortunately, but definitely adds value to the discussion!